# List of model that render in different way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Let say I've a list of objects derived from abstract class **ModelA**. I want to pass to a view List of objects (let's **ModelB** and **ModelC** that are subclasses of **ModelA**).

```
class ClassB: ClassA
{
}
class ClassC: ClassA
{
}
```

I want to make these objects (ModelB, ModelC) know how to render itself (ModelC UI differs to ModelB UI). I think I should use Partial View, but I have no idea how.
What about the following apporach:
ModelsA stores path to the PartialView (as abstract property) - then ModelB (or C) overrides it and then I render it:

```
@foreach(var model in modelList)
{
    Html.RenderPartial(model.PartialPath, model)
}
```

Sorry if syntax is not correct, I want showonly idea.

Comment: By making the model know how to render itself, you're violating the MVC pattern. The model should have no understanding of how it's rendered on-screen; that's the domain of the view.

Comment: Ok. I understand that I should create separate partial view for ModelB and ModelC. So How can I associoate proper partial view with model instance when I want to render list of ModelA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about EditorTemplates and ViewTemplates e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx